# Can we use a text element or lines over the graph?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

I  created a bubble chart where i am using lines and text over the graph, i am getting preview in ireport but not in Jasper-server. Does any one know how to use these lines?

Comment: Please anyone can help me i am new in Jasper server.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't think you can do this.  When you view reports in JasperServer you are looking at html.  From what I know, you cannot have overlapping controls in html.  When you do, one of the controls will not appear.  I have had similar situations with reports I created.  Any time 2 controls overlap, one disappears.

Comment: Thanks Tom, i also tried to do the same thing but reports are not working.